# Selenium website log in script. - safely storing credentials

Tags: python, authentication, encryption, selenium-chromedriver

I've written a short script for logging in to a website using Python's Selenium package. In order to NOT show the user credentials explicitly in the script I've stored them in a separate JSON config file.

Packages:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import json
```

Webdriver initialization:

```
site_url = "mywebsite.com"
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled": False,
        "safebrowsing.enabled": True
        })
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(site_url)
```

Selecting login dropdown element, username and password fields through XPaths:

```
login_dropdown_path = """login_XPath"""
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, login_dropdown_path).click()
time.sleep(3)

username_field_path = """username_field_XPath"""
password_field_path = """password_field_XPath"""

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath(username_field_path)
username.clear()
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_field_path)
password.clear()
```

Opening the config.json with the stored credentials:

```
with open('config.json','r') as f:
  config = json.load(f)
```

Filling in username and password fields

```
username.send_keys(config['user']['username'])
password.send_keys(config['user']['password'])
```

Clicking on the Login button identified through its XPath:

```
login_button_path = """username_button_XPath"""
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, login_button_path).click()
time.sleep(3)
```

The JSON file is :

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "username",
    "password": "password"
  }
}
```

The script is intended for personal use only, but is there is a safer way to either store and potentially even encrypt the credentials??

Thanks!

Comment: you can use symmetric key encryption, but you need to memorize the key or save it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt/decrypt the credentials file itself if you just want to avoid storing the credentials in plain text. Of course, if a third party knew how to decrypt the encrypted file you'd be in the same boat, but it's another layer nonetheless.

https://github.com/M4cs/objcrypt may be one such solution.